# Cannot find Nvidia driver with pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

I am following this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nvidia#Installing

The command `pacman -S nvidia` fails with `error: target not found: nvidia`, indeed, even `packman -Ss nvidia` to search for it results in no matches, the only package found under extra that matches "nvidia" is `extra/libcl`.

My `/etc/pacman.conf` does have `[extra]` repository enabled (as can be seen in the search successfully finding one item in the extra repository).

Maybe pacman's list is out of date. I have run `pacman -Sy`.

This means that I'm completely stuck now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that you were getting the "target not found" message is that your local pacman database was being used to reference a target (`nvidia`) that no longer existed on the mirrors, as it had since been replaced by a newer version.

The correct, and only safe, way to fix this is to first force an update of your local database with `pacman -Syy` and then do a full upgrade with `pacman -Syu`. This will ensure that all packages and their libraries are updated at the same time, preventing [the possibility of breakage](http://gist.io/5660494).

These commands can be combined with `pacman -Syyu`.

Answer (score 1):

`pacman -Syy` updated my repos and now I was able to fetch nvidia.

From Arch docs:

> Tip: Passing two --refresh or -y flags forces pacman to refresh all package lists even if they are considered to be up to date. Issuing pacman -Syy whenever changing to a new mirror is good practice and will avoid possible issues.

Something got screwed up (this machine wasn't connected to the internet for a long time, but there obviously should have been an nvidia package back when I installed Arch. No idea what went wrong here)

Comment: Note that, as [@jasonwryan](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150829/65525) mentioned, you should [_never_ install packages with with `pacman -Sy`](http://gist.io/5660494).

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the emphasis. Dare I say, Arch can be a little bit treacherous! I mean, why does the `-Sy` option even exist? It could at least issue a little warning when you run it that way.